# Retrieve the status(failure/success) of Spark application in Spark Standalone mode with client deploy mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running Spark cluster in standalone mode and doing `spark-submit` to submit Spark applications in `client` deploy mode. I would like to get the status (whether success or failure) of the Spark application.

The reason I have to use `client` deploy mode is that, we are running both Scala and Python Spark applications and `cluster` deploy mode does not support Python Spark applications by now.

The approach I can think of is to start the Spark history server and then use [its REST endpoint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) to query for status from `<app-id>` and looking for whether there's failed job under the app (Because unfortunately, `spark-master:8080/json` only gives whether the app is running or completed, not fail/succeed). Next, to get the app-id in `client` deploy mode, I have to grep and match the log4j line

```
StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-xxxxxxx-xxx
```

I'm wondering is there better approach than this, I've been searching around, but the solution given is all for YARN or `cluster` deploy mode.